# value with apostrophe are not inserted correctly in NSmutableDictionary

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

I want to create a dictionary with key "name" and number with value "George’s iPhone" and "123456".

**My code is:**

```
NSString *name = @"George’s iPhone";
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[dict setValue:@"123456" forKey:@"number"];
[dict setValue:name forKey:@"name"];
```

**but i got,**

```
name = "George\U2019s iPhone";
value = "123456";
```

Comment: Since `Nsstring` is a typo, I have to ask whether this _really_ your code as you're using it. The output `George\U2019s iPhone` would be normal in the debugger output. But what is `value` supposed to be?

Comment: Is this output from debugger? If yes it's correctly. If it's on label, it's wrong. I thing it's from debugger.

Comment: this string contains an UNICode char, What is your text source ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your code, nor is there anything wrong with the output.

`\U2019` is an escape sequence that works out to the desired character.

Now, you probably wanted `'`, and not `’`, but that's really neither here nor there.

Answer (score 0):

When you are doing the initialization of your string, `NSString` is picking up the correct string encoding for you which is probably `UTF8`. So your apostrophe is \U2019 in unicode. Nothing wrong in your code: what you are seeing in debugger or an NSLog is correct here.

Answer (score 0):

You used:

```
NSLog(@"%@", dict);
```

That's why it shows like the output. In `NSDictionary`, the `'`  character is encoded.

You can check with:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [dict valueForKey:@"name"]);
```

It'll print the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:-

```
NSDictionary *yourDict=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"George’s iPhone",@"123456",nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"name",@"number",nil]];
NSLog(@"%@",[[yourDict valueForKey:@"name"]stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]);
NSLog(@"%@",[[yourDict valueForKey:@"number"]stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]);
```

Comment: here using stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet which will delete whitespaces